# ER-Modelling: A relationship with multiple but different uses. How to go about mapping this?

Tags: database-design

A random, sort of ridiculous scenario:
A grocery store requires its employees record information pertaining to their job.

Say you have three entities under a ISA hierarchy:a cleaner, a shelf stocker, and a cashier. They all use the relationship "records" but they record completely different things. The cleaner entity records each product used and how much is used, the shelf stocker records inventory before restocking, and the cashier records amount of cash left in the cash register at the end of the day.

If only one relationship "record" is used, then it may become confusing since the lines could mean that a cleaner not only records the amount of cleaning products used, but inventory as well as remaining cash in the cash register.

There is the possibility of writing three relationships called "records" but that would be redundant and inefficient for a DBMS.

[image: Random scenario for scenario]

Answer (score 0):

ISA hierarchies are sometimes referred to as Generalization/Specialization in ER modeling.  However, ER modeling does not think in terms of "records".  Records pertain to a particular class of databases, ones that store data in records.

All of the major SQL databases store data in records, so we can go with that.  And, if we think of a physical record as representing a tuple in a logical (relational) model, we can apply your question to a broader class of databases.

As to how to model an ISA relationship in a relational model or an SQL model, I refer you to two buzzwords that may help:  Single Table Inheritance and Class Table Inheritance.  Some research on these should give you two alternative design approaches.